# No data in first page in pager adapter

Tags: java, android, android-pageradapter

I create adapter when click on Item in activity. The first page is empty. When I slide it over (to the third page content there is present) and come back content is there.

```
public void showItem(){     
    mSwipeAdapter = new SwipeAdapter(mItemsList);       
    mSwipePager.setAdapter(mSwipeAdapter);      
    this.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

And adapter

```
   private class SwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {        
    List<Item> mSwipeItems;

    public SwipeAdapter(List<Item> mItems) {
        mSwipeItems = mItems;
    }

    @Override       
    public int getCount() {     
        return mSwipeItems.size();          
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        mCurrentContentView = new ContentView(mContext);                        
        mCurrentItem = mSwipeItems.get(position);
        mCurrentContentView.showItem(mCurrentItem);         
        collection.addView(mCurrenContentView);
        return mCurrentContentView;
    }   

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }
    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }      
}
```

I find here the same problem [First viewpager page blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265384/first-viewpager-page-blank) but there no solution.

Comment: Try to call `mSwipePager.notifyDataSetChanged();` after you create it.

Comment: I tried but it did not help